# Network is DHCP - Can I manually set an IP to a device?

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

So as of right now, our SonicWall controls DHCP leasing. We have a bunch of network objects that really need to remain static (I plan on converting the network to static later), but I need a fix in the meantime.

Since SonicWall does not have the option for DHCP reservations as Windows does, would I be able to manually assign something a permanent address and have that work? Even after a reboot and it gets back on the network, would a manually addressed device be okay?

Comment: Which SonicWall do you have that doesn't allow you to set static entries for DHCP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just make sure you set the static IP outside the DHCP range, and on the same subnet.